# Error when updating the values of a column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying the following:

```
update Question set CreatedBy = "02712b8a-1f32-49bc-911b-d3ee4d0c9d90"
```

But this give me an error:

```
Invalid column name '02712b8a-1f32-49bc-911b-d3ee4d0c9d90'.
```

When I try the following it works good and lists values:

```
select createdby from question
```

I have checked and from what I understand the syntax of my update is correct. Can anyone see what might be wrong. Why does it assume the long string is a column name. Note that the datatype of CreatedBy is UNIQUEIDENTIFIER.

Comment: Change double quotes to single quotes

Comment: Double quotes used for identifiers (columns names, table names, etc), single quotes for literals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx) must be on. With this, SQL Server follows the ANSI standard which dictates double-quotes (`"`) are for *identifiers* and single-quotes (`'`) are for string literals. Therefore it is interpreting `02712b8a-1f32-49bc-911b-d3ee4d0c9d90` as a column name, not a string value as you intend; your query is synonymous with:

```
update Question set CreatedBy = [02712b8a-1f32-49bc-911b-d3ee4d0c9d90]
```

---

The solution - Use single-quotes instead:

```
update Question set CreatedBy = '02712b8a-1f32-49bc-911b-d3ee4d0c9d90'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is double quotes. Try this

```
update Question set CreatedBy = '02712b8a-1f32-49bc-911b-d3ee4d0c9d90'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are comparing varchar value against a string value & in sql string should be written with single-quotes

so problem is with double quotes , use single quotes instead.

```
update question set createdby = 'your value goes here'
```

thanks

hope it works